# Paginating a solr response using kaminari?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

Does kaminari support pagination of a solr response ? If yes, how to convert the response to a kaminari-compatible format ?

Answer (score 2):

Set up Kaminari for your project as described here - http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari

In your controller, if you have the following to perform the Solr search -

```
@vehicles = Vehicles.search do

     with (:year => 2012)
     paginate :page => params[:page],  :per_page => 20

end
```

You need to add the following in your view to get the pagination links -

```
<%= paginate @vehicles.hits %>
```

Hope that helps!